# How do I create bold text in email using Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am using the submission of a Google Form to fill a Google Sheet. On the form submission an email will be generated to the recipient addressed in the form via the Google App Script in the Google Sheet. In this email, I would like to make the title/positions "Director of Bands and Choirs' and "Honors Choir Coordinator" listed in my email signature bold. If I can also make my name appear larger in the signature, that would be nice as well.

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {

const info = e.namedValues;
const pdfFile = createPDF(info);
const entryRow = e.range.getRow();
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
ws.getRange(entryRow, 5).setValue(pdfFile.getUrl());
ws.getRange(entryRow, 6).setValue(pdfFile.getName());

sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email'][0],pdfFile);

}


function sendEmail(email,pdfFile){


GmailApp.sendEmail(email, "Honors Choir", "Esteemed Colleague, \n\nAttached to this email is a                 confirmation of registration & receipt of payment for the Honors Choir. \n\nAdditionally, it appears that music for the concert is on backorder. I will share a folder with scans of the music with you soon. However, please make sure to support our fellow musicians by ordering the originals. \n\nSincerely, \nMy Name \n<b>Director of Bands and Choirs</b> \nA Michigan High School | School Address | City, State ZIP CODE\nWebsite.com | Facebook: Account \n\nHonors Choir Coordinator \nwww.Website.org | Facebook: Account",    {
attachments: [pdfFile],
name: 'Honors Choir Coordinator'
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might get you started in the right direction.  If you structure your email something like this, you can get the formatting you desire in the body of the email.

Try replacing your function `sendEmail()` with the following code:

```
function sendEmail() {
  

  var html_body =  "Esteemed colleagues,<br><br>"
                 + "Such and such text... <br><br>"
                 + "Sincerely, <br>"
                 + "<big><b>My Name </big></b><br>"
                 + "<b>Director of Bands and Choirs </b><br><br>"
                 + "Additional information not in bold<br>"
                 + "<b>Additional information in bold.</b><br>"
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "soandso@suchandsuch.com",
    subject: "Honors Choir",
    htmlBody: html_body
  });

  
}
```

Let me know how it goes.